# Add opening and closing balance columns

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I have a table like this:

```
StockNumber|InventoryName|Year|Month|Adj|iss|piss|Tsfr|return|rdj|rpo|xefr
alb001      clinic1       2010  1     4   5    5   5    6      5   4   10
alb001      Clinic1       2010  2    10  2    2    3    3      4   4   4
alb001      Clinic1       2010  4    11  3   5    77    90     78   9   6
alb001      Clinic1       2010  5    10  2    2    3    3      4   4   4
```

I want to add a closing balance column which will be

```
sum(return+rdj+rpo+xefr) - sum(adj+iss+piss+tsfr)
```

I also want to add the opening balance column which will be the be the closing balance of the previous month.

I will then calculate the current months balance as:

```
OpeningBalance + sum(return+rdj+rpo+xefr) - sum(adj+iss+piss+tsfr) = ClosingBalance
```

**NB.** The Year and Month columns are floats and also want to change them to date  format.

I am newbie to SQL and crystal reports. I want a query to help me achieve the tasks of developing a report that has the opening and closing balance columns, the opening balance being the previous closing balance.

Comment: the closing balance =opening balance+ (return+rdj+rpo+xefr)-(adj+iss+piss+tsfr) for each month..the grouping is per clinics as an example because we have several clinics..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
;WITH WithClosingBalances
AS
(
    SELECT
      [StockNumber], 
      [InventoryName], 
      [Year], 
      [Month], 
      [Adj], 
      [iss],
      [piss], 
      [Tsfr], 
      [return], 
      [rdj], 
      [rpo], 
      [xefr],
      ([return] + rdj + rpo + xefr) -
      (adj+iss+piss+tsfr) ClosingBalance,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INVENTORYNAME
                        ORDER BY month) rownum
    FROM table1
), WithOpeningBalances
AS
(
    SELECT
      [StockNumber], 
      [InventoryName], 
      [Year], 
      [Month], 
      [Adj], 
      [iss],
      [piss], 
      [Tsfr], 
      [return], 
      [rdj], 
      [rpo], 
      [xefr],
      ClosingBalance,
      ISNULL((SELECT ClosingBalance 
             FROM WithClosingBalances c2
             WHERE c1.rownum - c2.rownum =1
            ), 0) OpeningBalance,
      rownum
    FROM WithClosingBalances c1
) 
SELECT
  [StockNumber], 
  [InventoryName], 
  [Year], 
  [Month], 
  [Adj], 
  [iss],
  [piss], 
  [Tsfr], 
  [return], 
  [rdj], 
  [rpo], 
  [xefr],
  ClosingBalance,
  OpeningBalance,
  OpeningBalance + ClosingBalance AS CurrentMonthBalance
FROM WithOpeningBalances;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0d3/6)

This will give you:

```
| STOCKNUMBER | INVENTORYNAME | YEAR | MONTH | ADJ | ISS | PISS | TSFR | RETURN | RDJ | RPO | XEFR | CLOSINGBALANCE | OPENINGBALANCE | CURRENTMONTHBALANCE |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      alb001 |       clinic1 | 2010 |     1 |   4 |   5 |    5 |    5 |      6 |   5 |   4 |   10 |              6 |              0 |                   6 |
|      alb001 |       Clinic1 | 2010 |     2 |  10 |   2 |    2 |    3 |      3 |   4 |   4 |    4 |             -2 |              6 |                   4 |
|      alb001 |       Clinic1 | 2010 |     4 |  11 |   3 |    5 |   77 |     90 |  78 |   9 |    6 |             87 |             -2 |                  85 |
|      alb001 |       Clinic1 | 2010 |     5 |  10 |   2 |    2 |    3 |      3 |   4 |   4 |    4 |             -2 |             87 |                  85 |
```

---

### How does this query work?

This query will evaluate, `CLOSINGBALANCE`, `OPENINGBALANCE, and`CURRENTMONTHBALANCE` as I understand from your question, as following:

- **`CLOSINGBALANCE`** =

  ```
    [return] + rdj + rpo + xefr) -
    (adj+iss+piss+tsfr)
  ```

  For each month. I assumed that each record in your table for each month.
- **`OPENINGBALANCE`**: is the `CLOSINGBALANCE` of the previous month grouped by inventory name. This is done using the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY InventoryName)`.
- **`CURRENTMONTHBALANCE`** = `OpeningBalance + ClosingBalance` for each record.

---

**Update:** You can use `JOIN` instead of a correlated subquery, in case there were multiple months entry, like so:

```
;WITH WithClosingBalances
AS
(
    SELECT
      [StockNumber], 
      [InventoryName], 
      [Year], 
      [Month], 
      [Adj], 
      [iss],
      [piss], 
      [Tsfr], 
      [return], 
      [rdj], 
      [rpo], 
      [xefr],
      ([return] + rdj + rpo + xefr) -
      (adj+iss+piss+tsfr) ClosingBalance,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INVENTORYNAME
                        ORDER BY month) rownum
    FROM table1
), WithOpeningBalances
AS
(
    SELECT
      [StockNumber], 
      [InventoryName], 
      [Year], 
      [Month], 
      [Adj], 
      [iss],
      [piss], 
      [Tsfr], 
      [return], 
      [rdj], 
      [rpo], 
      [xefr],
      c1.ClosingBalance,
      ISNULL(c2.ClosingBalance, 0) OpeningBalance
    FROM WithClosingBalances c1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
      SELECT rownum, SUM(ClosingBalance) ClosingBalance
      FROM WithClosingBalances
      GROUP BY rownum
    ) c2 ON c1.rownum - c2.rownum = 1
) 
SELECT
  [StockNumber], 
  [InventoryName], 
  [Year], 
  [Month], 
  [Adj], 
  [iss],
  [piss], 
  [Tsfr], 
  [return], 
  [rdj], 
  [rpo], 
  [xefr],
  ClosingBalance,
  OpeningBalance,
  OpeningBalance + ClosingBalance AS CurrentMonthBalance
FROM WithOpeningBalances;
```

This will give you the same output.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0d3/12)

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.  i get that error when trying to run the script....i am using SQL 2005....i didn't want the CurrentMonth balance but it might be a good thing to have in the report..i wanted the closing balance of January to be the opening balance of February as an example.and the calcution of February will be done based on the opening balance of january as an example.

Comment: @user1862899 - Try to user `JOIN` with `SUM` like what I did in my edit. See my updated answer. Note that the closing balance is computed the same way you described, test it. It should work fine each month has the opening balance = closing balance of the previous month.

Comment: the query runs fine but i want do away with the CurrentMonthBalance column,....... and i also wanted it to be like this,if the closing balance for january s 60 then when we calculate balance for february that 60 must be shown in its column..this more like a bank statement account kind of thing.they show you how much you were left with last month and add that amount to the current balance.thank you though sir.

Comment: @user1862899 Do you mean adding a new column  previous month closing balance. Can you please modify [this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0d3/12) with a sample of the data you already working on. Press the button 'Text To DDL` then past the data with the column names and then it will create a new table with these data, and please explain what is the desired output. So far you didn't need the `currentmonthBalance` column, and the closingBalance and the openingabalance are computed the right way. right?